# Getting the element of a list with maximum "value" as calculated by another function

Tags: list, haskell, types

I have this data and types

```
data Cliente = Uncliente {nombre::String,resistencia::Int,bebidas::[Bebida],amigos::[Cliente]} deriving (Show) 

type Bebida = Cliente -> Cliente 

type Nombre = String
type Duracion = Float
type Acciones = [Bebida]
type Itinerario = (Nombre,Duracion,Acciones)
```

i have this functions:

This function takes an itinerario and a cliente and return a client with values modified.

```
realizarItinerario :: Itinerario -> Cliente -> Cliente
realizarItinerario itinerario cliente = tomarTragos cliente (conseguirAcciones itinerario)
```

I have this function that lets you know the intensity of each itinerario

```
conocerIntensidad :: Itinerario -> Float
conocerIntensidad (nombre,duracion,acciones) = ((genericLength acciones)/duracion)
```

This is an auxiliary function :

```
conseguirAcciones :: Itinerario -> [Bebida]
conseguirAcciones (_,_,acciones) = acciones
```

And i need to create a function that given a list of Itinerarios and a Client, it return the client with the Highest Intensity itinerario applied to him:

I know how to get the highest itinerario but dont know how to apply it on the same function.

Comment: Please try to give more descriptive titles to your questions -- "Lists and tuples in haskell" could mean pretty much anything. (If you have difficulties with summarising your question into a short yet meaningful title, that might be a sign that your question isn't clear or specific enough.)

Comment: fst . maximumBy (comparing snd) . map (\x -> (x,conocerIntensidad x))`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

applyHighestIntensityItinerario :: [Itinerario] -> Cliente -> Cliente
applyHighestIntensityItinerario itinerarios cliente =
  let itinerario = maximumBy (comparing conocerIntensidad) itinerarios
  in  realizarItinerario itinerario cliente
```

Here, `maximumBy (comparing conocerIntensidad)` chooses the element of the list `itinerarios` whose intensity as computed by `conocerIntensidad` has maximum value.  `maximumBy` comes from `Data.List`, and `comparing` comes from `Data.Ord`.

Then, the `let` clause is used to assign it to a variable `itinerario` and apply it using the helper function `realizarItinerario`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. It works excelent